# curl request in groovy throws syntax error

Tags: curl, jenkins, groovy, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to execute a curl request in groovy, but it throws syntax error:

```
def pyString = "import json,sys;text=str(sys.stdin.read().strip());obj=json.loads(text);print ([dict['id'] for dict in obj if dict['name_with_namespace']=='prjs/myProj'])"
def pyCmdArray = ["python", "-c", ${pyString}]
def pyCmdOutput = pyCmdArray.execute()
println "Here you are: "
println pyCmdOutput.text()
def responseUrl = "https://abc.dev.sys/api/v3/projects?per_page=100"+pyCmdOutput.text()
def response = (curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" -H "Content-Type:application/json" ${responseUrl})
```

Error is:

```
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 29: expecting ')', found 'PRIVATE-TOKEN:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy' @ line 29, column 27.
     def response = (curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" -H "Content-Type:application/json" ${responseUrl})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `HttpUrlConnection` or a HTTP library such as `http-builder-ng` to make the request instead of executing `curl` as a separate process?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of tweaking, I was able to make this work

```
def response = ["curl", "-H", "private_token:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "-H", "Content-Type:application/json", responseUrl].execute().text
```